# Is there a package to set the default font encoding of cyrillic to T2A?

Tags: fonts, babel, font-encodings, cyrillic

Consider this for Greek

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textalpha}
\begin{document}
φύσις
\end{document
```

As the default font supports LGR encoding, it renders correctly:

[image]

I am looking for similar effect for occasional Cyrillic letters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
% ? \usepackage
\begin{document}
До свидания!
\end{document}
```

Currently this fails with

```
LaTeX Error: Command \CYRD unavailable in encoding T1.
```

I must add manually

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\CYRD}{T2A}
\begin{document}
До свидания!
\end{document}
```

then it fails at next letter:

```
LaTeX Error: Command \cyro unavailable in encoding T1.
```

So

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\CYRD}{T2A}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyro}{T2A}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyrs}{T2A}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyrv}{T2A}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyri}{T2A}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyrd}{T2A}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyra}{T2A}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyrn}{T2A}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyrya}{T2A}
\begin{document}
До свидания!
\end{document}
```

[image]

I need some such automated font encoding substitution, and no extra mark-up.

I tried

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,main=english]{babel}

\begin{document}
До свидания!
\end{document}
```

but this still fails.

This is `pdflatex` only question. No extra mark-up in body of the type `\textcyrillic` is allowed. As indicated above I have an idea of what to do, but this is a bit fastidious and I will not know how to handle accents (this is optional; basic cyrillic support only is asked for. No hyphenation is needed).

---

(moved from comments)

The suggestion `T1,T2A` in place of `T2A,T1` has the problem that Latin accented letters will be rendered with accent macros and not be copyable-pastable from the PDF. Here is for example for `é`:

```
....\kern -0.27771 (for accent)
....\T2A/cmr/m/n/10 ^^A
....\kern -4.72107 (for accent)
....\T2A/cmr/m/n/10 e
```

I do need to support European languages. Typically the document will use `babel` with a Latin language as main language, and the goal is support for occasional Cyrillic letters or words (without caring for proper hyphenation) with minimal overhead and no extra mark-up in body.

Comment: I am probably missing something obvious, but... loading `\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}` seems to work (_i.e._ changing the order of `T1` and `T2A`).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik good idea but unfortunately it slows down diacritics in Latin language such as `é, è, ç` and typesets them as accents, so that copy paste from PDF does not work. However for pure English this could be good option. But I do need support for European languages.

Comment: Strange... although the accent is different in the log, the copy-paste still works for me. Here's my theory: It's not possible without switching the encoding. If you do `\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont éèç\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont До свидания!` you can see in the log that the `и` cyrillic letter is written as `\T2A/cmr/m/n/10 è`, so it's probably in the same position as the latin `è` so, for me it looks like you will, at least, need an encoding witch. Beware that my level of certainty is pretty much null :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The `\DeclareTextSymbolDefault` in my OP are there to activate such an automatic font encoding switch. I hope for a package having them all prepared so that I don't have to do it myself.

Comment: Oh, there goes the obvious thing I'm missing :P (and the "encoding witch", which I thought too funny to correct :)

Comment: the default encoding mechanism was only intended to pull odd symbols from the text companion encoding and the like. If the main document is in cyrillic that should be the last encoding specified, and if your main document is in latin but you use cyrillic letters without switching encoding then essentially you will switch encoding "for each letter" so mess up inter-letter kerns and hyphenation for cyrillic. In any mixed language document if you switch language so set up the correct hyphenation and font encoding then this shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have in sight Latin document with occasional Cyrillic letters (for math notation e.g. Ш). They will be produced from other input mark-up and no language switching mechanism is available. The `textalpha` package does for Greek exactly what I need. Breaking inter-letter kerns and hyphenation is no issue at all in my context. Package `textalpha` provides for Greek what I need for Cyrillic.

Comment: Your code will not work in math (and the code with the \textalpha neither). This sounds as if you are trying to misuse some side effects, to avoid proper markup and definitions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I know about math. This is why `alphabeta` package exists, but it uses approach to map for example a α to `\alpha`, where as some people would like it to use the text font (via amsmath `\text{..}` for example). My context is one where Python tools are used to convert some mark-up to LaTeX. Currently multiple languages input are not supported, but occasional use of Greek (beta-decay) or Cyrillic (author names) may be needed. LaTeX with its constraints and internal logic is not the ultimate decision-maker here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I mentioned the Ш letter above as math-related but wasn't meaning to use it in math mode. My question is about text mode only. For math mode I can tell people in my context to switch to XeLaTeX and unicode-math if they want Unicode input in math. My aim here is pdfLaTeX only. Remarkably, Japanese pLaTeX handles individual Greek and Cyrillic letters both in text and math mode with no extra user set-up, and out-of-the box (say with `jreport` class and default fonts there).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variant of your own answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\@tfor\next:=%
  {А}{а}{Б}{б}{В}{в}{Г}{г}{Д}{д}{Е}{е}
  {Ё}{ё}{Ж}{ж}{З}{з}{И}{и}{Й}{й}{К}{к}
  {Л}{л}{М}{м}{Н}{н}{О}{о}{П}{п}{Р}{р}
  {С}{с}{Т}{т}{У}{у}{Ф}{ф}{Х}{х}{Ц}{ц}
  {Ч}{ч}{Ш}{ш}{Щ}{щ}{Ъ}{ъ}{Ы}{ы}{Ь}{ь}
  {Э}{э}{Ю}{ю}{Я}{я}%
\do{%
  \begingroup\def\IeC{\protect\DeclareTextSymbolDefault}%
  \protected@edef\@temp{\endgroup\csname u8:\next\endcsname{X2}}\@temp}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

До свидания! See you soon!

\end{document}
```

Add other Cyrillic characters you need. Remember that, if you're running an older LaTeX release (prior to 2018-04-01), you need also `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

[image]

Using the X2 encoding, that covers a larger number of characters in the encodings T2A, T2B and T2C:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[X2,T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\@tfor\next:=
{Ё} {Ђ} {Є} {Ѕ} {І} {Ј} {Љ} {Њ} {Ћ} {Ў} {Џ} {А} {Б} {В} {Г} {Д}
{Е} {Ж} {З} {И} {Й} {К} {Л} {М} {Н} {О} {П} {Р} {С} {Т} {У} {Ф}
{Х} {Ц} {Ч} {Ш} {Щ} {Ъ} {Ы} {Ь} {Э} {Ю} {Я} {а} {б} {в} {г} {д}
{е} {ж} {з} {и} {й} {к} {л} {м} {н} {о} {п} {р} {с} {т} {у} {ф}
{х} {ц} {ч} {ш} {щ} {ъ} {ы} {ь} {э} {ю} {я} {ё} {ђ} {є} {ѕ} {і}
{ј} {љ} {њ} {ћ} {ў} {џ} {Ѣ} {ѣ} {Ѫ} {ѫ} {Ѵ} {ѵ} {Ґ} {ґ} {Ғ} {ғ}
{Ҕ} {ҕ} {Җ} {җ} {Ҙ} {ҙ} {Қ} {қ} {Ҝ} {ҝ} {Ҟ} {ҟ} {Ҡ} {ҡ} {Ң} {ң}
{Ҥ} {ҥ} {Ҧ} {ҧ} {Ҩ} {ҩ} {Ҫ} {ҫ} {Ҭ} {ҭ} {Ү} {ү} {Ұ} {ұ} {Ҳ} {ҳ}
{Ҵ} {ҵ} {Ҷ} {ҷ} {Ҹ} {ҹ} {Һ} {һ} {Ҽ} {ҽ} {Ҿ} {ҿ} {Ӏ} {Ӄ} {ӄ} {Ӆ}
{ӆ} {Ӈ} {ӈ} {Ӌ} {ӌ} {Ӎ} {ӎ} {Ӕ} {ӕ} {Ә} {ә} {Ӡ} {ӡ} {Ө} {ө}
\do{%
  \begingroup\def\IeC{\protect\DeclareTextSymbolDefault}%
  \protected@edef\@temp{\endgroup\csname u8:\next\endcsname{X2}}\@temp}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Ё Ђ Є Ѕ І Ј Љ Њ Ћ Ў Џ А Б В Г Д
Е Ж З И Й К Л М Н О П Р С Т У Ф
Х Ц Ч Ш Щ Ъ Ы Ь Э Ю Я а б в г д
е ж з и й к л м н о п р с т у ф
х ц ч ш щ ъ ы ь э ю я ё ђ є ѕ і
ј љ њ ћ ў џ Ѣ ѣ Ѫ ѫ Ѵ ѵ Ґ ґ Ғ ғ
Ҕ ҕ Җ җ Ҙ ҙ Қ қ Ҝ ҝ Ҟ ҟ Ҡ ҡ Ң ң
Ҥ ҥ Ҧ ҧ Ҩ ҩ Ҫ ҫ Ҭ ҭ Ү ү Ұ ұ Ҳ ҳ
Ҵ ҵ Ҷ ҷ Ҹ ҹ Һ һ Ҽ ҽ Ҿ ҿ Ӏ Ӄ ӄ Ӆ
ӆ Ӈ ӈ Ӌ ӌ Ӎ ӎ Ӕ ӕ Ә ә Ӡ ӡ Ө ө


\end{document}
```

[image]

To your delight, an implementation with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[X2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__recode:N
 {% #1 is \u8:<bytes> which expands to \IeC{<LICR>}
  \exp_last_unbraced:No \__recode_aux:nn #1
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__recode_aux:nn { \DeclareTextSymbolDefault#2{X2} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__recode:N { c }
\tl_map_inline:nn
 {
  {Ё} {Ђ} {Є} {Ѕ} {І} {Ј} {Љ} {Њ} {Ћ} {Ў} {Џ} {А} {Б} {В} {Г} {Д}
  {Е} {Ж} {З} {И} {Й} {К} {Л} {М} {Н} {О} {П} {Р} {С} {Т} {У} {Ф}
  {Х} {Ц} {Ч} {Ш} {Щ} {Ъ} {Ы} {Ь} {Э} {Ю} {Я} {а} {б} {в} {г} {д}
  {е} {ж} {з} {и} {й} {к} {л} {м} {н} {о} {п} {р} {с} {т} {у} {ф}
  {х} {ц} {ч} {ш} {щ} {ъ} {ы} {ь} {э} {ю} {я} {ё} {ђ} {є} {ѕ} {і}
  {ј} {љ} {њ} {ћ} {ў} {џ} {Ѣ} {ѣ} {Ѫ} {ѫ} {Ѵ} {ѵ} {Ґ} {ґ} {Ғ} {ғ}
  {Ҕ} {ҕ} {Җ} {җ} {Ҙ} {ҙ} {Қ} {қ} {Ҝ} {ҝ} {Ҟ} {ҟ} {Ҡ} {ҡ} {Ң} {ң}
  {Ҥ} {ҥ} {Ҧ} {ҧ} {Ҩ} {ҩ} {Ҫ} {ҫ} {Ҭ} {ҭ} {Ү} {ү} {Ұ} {ұ} {Ҳ} {ҳ}
  {Ҵ} {ҵ} {Ҷ} {ҷ} {Ҹ} {ҹ} {Һ} {һ} {Ҽ} {ҽ} {Ҿ} {ҿ} {Ӏ} {Ӄ} {ӄ} {Ӆ}
  {ӆ} {Ӈ} {ӈ} {Ӌ} {ӌ} {Ӎ} {ӎ} {Ӕ} {ӕ} {Ә} {ә} {Ӡ} {ӡ} {Ө} {ө}
 }
 {
  \__recode:c { u8: \tl_to_str:n { #1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Ё Ђ Є Ѕ І Ј Љ Њ Ћ Ў Џ А Б В Г Д
Е Ж З И Й К Л М Н О П Р С Т У Ф
Х Ц Ч Ш Щ Ъ Ы Ь Э Ю Я а б в г д
е ж з и й к л м н о п р с т у ф
х ц ч ш щ ъ ы ь э ю я ё ђ є ѕ і
ј љ њ ћ ў џ Ѣ ѣ Ѫ ѫ Ѵ ѵ Ґ ґ Ғ ғ
Ҕ ҕ Җ җ Ҙ ҙ Қ қ Ҝ ҝ Ҟ ҟ Ҡ ҡ Ң ң
Ҥ ҥ Ҧ ҧ Ҩ ҩ Ҫ ҫ Ҭ ҭ Ү ү Ұ ұ Ҳ ҳ
Ҵ ҵ Ҷ ҷ Ҹ ҹ Һ һ Ҽ ҽ Ҿ ҿ Ӏ Ӄ ӄ Ӆ
ӆ Ӈ ӈ Ӌ ӌ Ӎ ӎ Ӕ ӕ Ә ә Ӡ ӡ Ө ө

\end{document}
```

Comment: clever... but was loading `xparse` needed? `:)`

Comment: this is elegant but problem is how to know offhand one will not (if extending the list from the picking additional Unicode Cyrillic letters) assign T2A to a letter actually available only in T2B/T2C ?

Comment: @jfbu That's the standard Russian Cyrillic alphabet. For glyphs in other encodings the method is the same.

Comment: I think I will award the green tick, now that answer is freed from automatic `xparse` loading template... `:)`. (waiting  a while)

Comment: @jfbu I added a larger list using X2

Comment: @jfbu You can freely use this code, a reference to this answer suffices.

Comment: I incorporated your code to [Sphinx](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/commit/b67105b74060da5dd9f270462f58e482f8e8d4da) (cleaning up my comments here) (sorry for spammenting)

Comment: Look at the edit history for a version running with LaTeX released prior than 2019.

Answer (score 3):

If no package exists, I might end up doing something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\@tfor\@tempa:=%
{ae}{a}{b}{chrdsc}{chvcrs}{ch}{c}{dje}{dze}{dzhe}{d}{erev}{ery}{e}%
{f}{ghcrs}{gup}{g}{hdsc}{hrdsn}{h}{ie}{ii}{ishrt}{i}{je}%
{kbeak}{kdsc}{kvcrs}{k}{lje}{l}{m}{ndsc}{ng}{nje}{n}{otld}{o}{p}{r}%
{schwa}{sdsc}{sftsn}{shch}{shha}{sh}{s}{tshe}{t}{ushrt}{u}{v}%
{ya}{yhcrs}{yi}{yo}{yu}{y}{zdsc}{zhdsc}{zh}{z}\do{%
    \expandafter\DeclareTextSymbolDefault\expandafter
               {\csname cyr\@tempa\endcsname}{T2A}%
    \expandafter\uppercase\expandafter{\expandafter
                 \def\expandafter\@tempa\expandafter{\@tempa}}%
    \expandafter\DeclareTextSymbolDefault\expandafter
      {\csname CYR\@tempa\endcsname}{T2A}%
}%
\makeatother
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\CYRpalochka}{T2A}

%\listfiles
\begin{document}
До свидания!

%\makeatletter
%\show\@uclclist
\end{document}
```

This was based on regex manipulation of `t2aenc.dfu` (I compared with `t2aenc.def` which has also `\cyrq`, `\cyrw`, but examination of Unicode Cyrillic block seems to indicate these stand simply for Latin `q` and `w`, so without explicit font encoding change in the document they can't be rendered by T2A encoded TeX font, another problem with my hoped-for "no mark-up" approach, besides breaking kerning and not setting up hyphenation).

The `\@uclclist` contains more `\cyr...`, presumably from `utf8enc.dfu` (one does not see it in  File List, but I guess because it is loaded in format since TL2018), so using it would mean assigning `T2A` default font encoding substitution wrongly to some letters. Which is not a problem if the document contains no such letters...

[image: da svidania]

Answer (score 2):

The following code is very hacky but still it doesn't make you list all cyrillic commands explicitly. The idea is to take the list somewhere, and there's a uppercase-lowercace conversion list with all `\cyr*` commands. So looping over `@uclclist` we can call `\DeclareTextSymbolDefault` for all cyrillic macros (there are some others in the list, like `\OE`, `\AE`, but declaring the default encoding for them seems to be harmless).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\def\myloop#1{%
\ifx\relax#1
  \let\next\relax
\else
  \let\next\myloop
  \DeclareTextSymbolDefault{#1}{T2A}
\fi
\next}
\expandafter\myloop\@uclclist\relax
\makeatother

\begin{document}
До свидания! é, è, ç, \OE, \ae
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, I could add a check for the macro name to start with `\cyr` or `\CYR`.

Comment: Right, I thought about that but decided to keep code simple at the moment.

Comment: an alternative could be to input `t2aenc.def` with special temporary meaning given to the macros it uses, but this is yet more hacky and possibly error prone. I suspect I may in the end simply copy-paste from that file and do some regex search/replace to prepare my own package, but I wouldn't know how to handle accents. I could also simply prepare a list of all `\cyr...` and `\CYR..` I see there and do a loop, with `\@tfor` e.g. At any rate, +1 for proposal.

Comment: the `\@uclclist` will contain `\cyrabhdze`, (presumably from a declaration inside `utf8enc.dfu`), but it is in T2B and T2C, not in T2A. So it would be wrong to use this trick, except of course if one is sure the document will contain no such letters available in T2B or T2C or X2 but not in T2A encoding. Besides, `\CYRpalochka` does not appear in the list presumably because there is no difference for it between lowercase and uppercase.